# How do I pause and cancel a dailymotion download that is going on using a firefox add-on?

Tags: firefox, video

I've just a little while ago installed a Mozilla Firefox add-on for downloading videos from the Dailymotion.Com, but inadvertently I've ended up clicking the "Download" button for a single video twice, resulting in starting two downloads of the identical video. I've tried right-clicking and then clicking "Pause" in the "Library" from Tools --> Downloads, but to no avail.

What should I do?

This is the link where I've downloaded the add-on:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/1-click-dailymotion-video-d/

Comment: Just cancelling one of the downloads doesn't work?

Comment: What do I do, @Karan? I've even tried ending the firefox process tree from the Task Manager, but the download resumes automatically as soon as Firefox starts again.

Comment: So you can't cancel the download, and whether you close Firefox normally or kill it, when you restart the download resumes? Looks like a badly coded add-on to me. I'd suggest disabling (or even uninstalling) the add-on and restarting Firefox. If you want you can reinstall again but you'll need to be careful with it in future obviously.